# Concatenating Strings whilst catering for nulls

Tags: sql, oracle, string-concatenation

I have the following script :-

```
select
siteid
address1,
address2,
address3,
address4,
address5
from tblsites
```

...which may returning something like :-

```
siteid address1     address2 address3   address4   address5
123    1 New Street NULL     New Town   NULL       Newvile
456    2 Elm Road   NULL     NULL       New York   New York
```

Is it possible in Oracle to reliably concatenate this data, catering for the nulls, and separating the strings with commas. So, the desired ouput for the data above is :-

```
siteid address
123    1 New Street, New Town, Newvile
456    2 Elm Road, New York, New York
```

Comment: To my knowledge there is nothing built in (like Postgres' `concat_ws()`) so you have to write your own function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `NVL2` to check whether the address components are non-null:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f6807/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tblsites ( siteid, address1, address2, address3, address4, address5 ) AS
  SELECT 123, '1 New Street', CAST( NULL AS VARCHAR2(50) ), 'New Town', NULL, 'Newvile' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 456, '2 Elm Road', NULL, NULL, 'New York', 'New York' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT siteid,
       RTRIM(
            NVL2( address1, address1 || ', ', NULL )
         || NVL2( address2, address2 || ', ', NULL )
         || NVL2( address3, address3 || ', ', NULL )
         || NVL2( address4, address4 || ', ', NULL )
         || NVL2( address5, address5 || ', ', NULL ),
         ', '
       ) AS address
FROM   tblsites
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5f6807/1/0)**:

```
| SITEID |                         ADDRESS |
|--------|---------------------------------|
|    123 | 1 New Street, New Town, Newvile |
|    456 |  2 Elm Road, New York, New York |
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT siteid,
       REGEXP_REPLACE((address1||','||address2||','||address3||','||address4||','||address5),'[,]+',',') AS address
FROM tblsites
```

**OUTPUT**

```
SITEID  ADDRESS
123     1 New Street,New Town,New vile
456     2 Elm Road,New York,New York
```

**DEMO**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/414cc/13

Comment: If the address has 2 or more `NULL` values in a row then the `REPLACE` will still leave instances of `,,`.

Comment: Check Now I Edited My answer @MT0